# How to programmatically change settings of input filters and activate them?

Tags: 7, input-formats

I'm looking for a way to programmatically change the settings of an input filter and activate it in Drupal 7. Let's take the Footnotes module as an example: It adds a new input filter that can be activated on input formats. I can navigate to `admin/config/content/formats/2` to edit my "Full HTML" input format and there activate the Footnote filter and configure it. But how can I achieve that programmatically?

My first guess was to load the input format using [filter_format_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_format_load/7), change some values and then do a [filter_format_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_format_save/7). But in the object that I get from filter_format_load(), there are no input filters, i.e. `$format->filters` doesn't exist.

I can get all available filters using [filter_list_format()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_list_format/7) and I believe I could change some values there. But then again, I can't find a way to save those settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the API page for the functions you mentioned in your question, you can easily see that there is a bug(or a feature) that it does not load populate `$filter->filters` indeed.

For a workaround, you could do something like this, with the help of [`filter_list_format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_list_format/7)

```
$format_id = 'full_html';
$filter_id = 'your_filter';
```

First, load the format object

```
$format = filter_format_load($format_id);
```

Now, since we do not have the `$filter->filters` populated, we do so by loading the currently enabled filters.

```
$filters = filter_list_format($format_id);
foreach ($filters as $filter_id => $filter_opts) { //Convert to an array, which is expected by the save function.
  $filters[$filter_id] = (array) $filter_opts;
}
```

You can now make changes in the filter that you are interested in.

```
$filters[$filter_id]['status'] = TRUE; //Enable. 
$filters[$filter_id]['settings']['something'] = 'foobar';
```

Inject filters to the format we have already loaded.

```
$format->filters = $filters;
```

Save!!

```
filter_format_save($format);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and interesting answer! Actually I thought about that, too. But in line 219 of filter.module I read that "Programmatic saves may not contain any filters" -- but it seems that's not really true. ;)

Comment: Two corrections though: $format_id would be numeric and the status would need to be set to 1/0, not TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: @AyeshK - this answer saved me a ton of time! Thank you so much for sharing! 
A tiny update - `$filters[$filter_id]['status'] = TRUE;` status accepts only integer values now so I used `$filters[$filter_id]['status'] = 1;` to enable the filter. Cheers!